# Hydrolysis of epoxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

There are two possibilities:

- Oxonium ion formation
- Cleaving of epoxide

Firstly, I don't know if epoxide is more reactive than carbonyl group.
If epoxide reacts with the proton,
[image]

But the given answer is:

[image]

In the above mechanism, an unstable carbocation is formed because its near a carbonyl group which is electron withdrawing:

[image]

Comment: The carbocation formation don't occurs. It's a concerted step.

Comment: Why? How do you know it has to be concerted?

Comment: You are correct in your last structure. This carbocation is very unstable, because this the mechanism is concerted. 

See the two products, whats more stable?

Comment: Both are equally stable? Are you referring steric repulsion? But the product in my answer is stabilized by conjugation which is not there in the answer given.

Comment: In your answer the second carbocation seems unstable and the final product in your answer is more unstable in relationship the correct answer.

I think that the product that you propound are a subproduct.

Comment: Are you sure the answer given in your type script photocopy is correct?  A Reaxys search of your starting material gives this paper, http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v75-242 which labels your starting material as cpd 12 and says that it gives the spiro diketone cpd 25  which has smiles string O=C1CCCC(C21CCCC2)=O and suggests an acyl migration.  In your diagram, the first protonated structure, the arrow would come from the bond between the carbonyl carbon and the hydroxyl carbon to the carbocation with subsequent loss of a proton.  Bear in mind the paper cited is from 1976.

Comment: I don't know. I will post the given options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go with your approach but your final product is unstable due to high repulsion's by $\pi$ electrons.

[image]

Hence your final product will react further to form a more thermodynamically feasible product.

[image]

NOTES:
In second structure two anti-periplanar migrations are possible and the one which leads to the more stable carbonation is favored (or consider the better migrating group based on electronegativity). Third structure rotates about spiral carbon due to repulsion's.

Comment: Is any kind of solvent required for such a rearrangement?